# listChildren returning zero count on rootFolder - googledrive apiMet

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I am getting zero child from the root folder while accessing my drive.

```
DriveFolder mFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mClient);
mFolder.listChildren(mClient).setResultCallback(mChilds);
```

and the callback is -

```
public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult arg0) {
    MetadataBuffer mBuffer = arg0.getMetadataBuffer();
    StringBuilder mBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = mBuffer.getCount();
    Iterator<Metadata> itr = mBuffer.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Metadata mData = itr.next();
        mBuilder.append(mData.getTitle() + "\n");
    }
    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    tView.setText(mBuilder.toString());
}
```

What am I doing wrong here??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copied your code into an activity of mine.  Replaced the `mBuilder` refs with a `Log` statement.  Saw children files listed, although _only_ files, not folders.  This differs from the documentation for `listChildren()` which states: "The result will include metadata for both files and folders".

Comment: @qbix What are the values/api you using when constructing the GoogleApiClient?? I am totally confused because I am always getting zero for listChildren on rootFolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with scope. Google play service library only supports Scope
    FILE_SCOPE
and
    APP_FOLDER_SCOPE
both can get file which is created with the application. 
The service library doesnot support full drive access. For this reason listChildren was returning 0 elements (meaning there was no file which was created by this application).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer; just easier to post code you requested here:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(SyncSettingsActivity.this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(SyncSettingsActivity.this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(SyncSettingsActivity.this)
        .build();
```